# What is better to design or discover interface

Tags: java, c#

Let's say you have some issue to develop. And as recommended practice it is good idea to use interfaces ( I don't mean GUI, I mean interface or abstract class ). And you can apply two ( I'm pretty sure, but for now I noticed I apply two ) ways:

1. Design interfaces upfront and then implement them.
2. Implement classes and then on basics of classes discover interface.

Personally I prefer second option, but during discussions with other developers I noticed that somebody prefers first approach. I can say that I prefer second approach for the following reasons:

- I can faster write code
- I avoid unnesessary code ( something that I never will use )
- Interfaces in that case are more binded to "real" life
- For me it is more convenient.
  I'd like to hear other advices why somebody prefers option 1 or option 2.
  As usually I code in C#, but AFAIK java also have idea of [interfaces](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_interfaces.htm)

Comment: 3. Design interfaces upfront, then write implementing classes, then finally discover all of your interfaces were wrong in the first place.

Comment: I think it is better to ask it on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: _Design interfaces_ vs _Implement classes_ ? Really? This is both wrong. __Design__ classes __and design__ Interfaces __and repeat__ until stable!

Comment: For me with anything really complex that tackles a wide range of use cases of which are impossible to foresee in entirety in advance, interfaces have to be discovered. I tend to consider whether I'm doing it right as to how many iterations it takes to achieve stability, and how difficult it was to apply each iteration. The trick to me is to keep the dependencies equally unstable and rough and minimal in number: enough to "discover" improvements but simple enough to afford a few minimally-cascading changes to code that's still very simple (a lot of which is going to be test code).